# How can i enable user to have reboot privileges without sudo?

Tags: permissions, ssh, shutdown, reboot

How can i enable user to have reboot privileges without sudo?
Need to keep sudo password enabled.

`ssh user@server "sudo reboot"` does not work because it requires a password to be entered.

Want this to work: `ssh user@server "reboot"`

i have tried /etc/shutdown.allow but  `reboot: Need to be root`

Comment: I think if you try ssh -t  user@<ip> sudo <command>  it will work

Comment: i had already tried the -t but that did not work either.  Adding NOPASSWD for specific commands is the way to go.